# How to Get Multiple values together in preg_match _all

Tags: php

Hey friends I have a problem with `preg_match_all` in PHP

I have output like this

```
"offerId" : 104, 
"offerName" : "Abcd", 
"alertText" : null,
"payoutType" : "REGISTER", 
"payoutDetails" : [ 
    { "propertyName" : "REGISTER",
      "propertyValue" : "1.0",
      "offerId" : 105, 
      "alertText" : null,
      "payoutType" : "REGISTER",
      "offerName" : "Abcdeeee", 
      "payoutDetails" : [ 
          { "propertyName" : "REGISTER",
            "propertyValue" : "1.0",
            "offerId" : 106,
            "offerName" : "Abcde", 
            "alertText" : null,
            "payoutType" : "REGISTER",
            "payoutDetails" : [
                { "propertyName" : "REGISTER",
                  "propertyValue" : "1.0"
```

Now I want to save values in this format according to offer id 1 by 1

```
offerid:-104 :offername-abcd:propertyValue:-1.0
```

I have tried `preg_match_all` but its not working for all values together 
what is the best way to store values in given format

Comment: Your output is incomplete... Please post the complete output (or at least a usable subset) and format it as I have done in my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Output is imcomplete. Look like JSON?
Anyway, with excess spaces removed:

```
$regex= "/\"offerId\" : (.*?), \"offerName\" : \"(.*?)\"/ms";

$subject='
"offerId" : 104, 
"offerName" : "Abcd", 
"alertText" : null,
"payoutType" : "REGISTER", 
"payoutDetails" : [ 
    { "propertyName" : "REGISTER",
      "propertyValue" : "1.0",
      "offerId" : 105, 
      "offerName" : "Abcdeeee",
      "alertText" : null,
      "payoutType" : "REGISTER", 
      "payoutDetails" : [ 
          { "propertyName" : "REGISTER",
            "propertyValue" : "1.0",
            "offerId" : 106,
            "offerName" : "Abcde", 
            "alertText" : null,
            "payoutType" : "REGISTER",
            "payoutDetails" : [
                { "propertyName" : "REGISTER",
                  "propertyValue" : "1.0"
                  ';
$subject = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $subject);

preg_match_all($regex, $subject, $matches);

print_r( $matches);
```

Run code: https://3v4l.org/WHaon

Comment: This solution would better with regex for Numbers Like [0-9]+